# r caret: train ONE model once the hyper-parameters are already known

Tags: r, r-caret

I am using caret to train a ridge regression:

```
library(ISLR)
Hitters = na.omit(Hitters)
x = model.matrix(Salary ~ ., Hitters)[, -1] #Dropping the intercept column.
y = Hitters$Salary

set.seed(0)
train = sample(1:nrow(x), 7*nrow(x)/10)

library(caret)
set.seed(0)
# Values of lambda over which to check:
grid = 10 ^ seq(5, -2, length = 100)
train_control = trainControl(method = 'cv', number = 10)
tune.grid = expand.grid(lambda = grid, alpha = 0)
ridge.caret = train(x[train, ], y[train],
                    method = 'glmnet',
                    trControl = train_control,
                    tuneGrid = tune.grid)
ridge.caret$bestTune
# alpha is 0 and best lambda is 242.0128
```

So, I found my optimal lambda and alpha. In fact, it's not really important for my question, what they are.

Now, how could I now run just ONE ridge regression (using caret) with alpha = 0 and lambda = 242.0128 for the whole data set?

I discovered that I can specify trainControl method as 'none'. See the code below. Did I correctly specify the tuneGrid (with just one line). Is this how it should be done?

Thank you very much!

```
set.seed(12345)
ridge_full <- train(x, y,
                    method = 'glmnet',
                    trControl = trainControl(method = 'none'), 
                    tuneGrid = expand.grid(lambda = ridge.caret$bestTune$lambda, alpha = 0))
coef(ridge_full$finalModel, s = ridge_full$bestTune$lambda)
```

Comment: Just use `glmnet` directly with the optimal parameters.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it using glmnet. However, I'd like to do it using 'caret'

Comment: yep. correct. see also documentation [here](http://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#fitting-models-without-parameter-tuning)

Comment: Thank you, phiver!